# Flux + React.js - Callback in actions is good or bad?

Tags: javascript, reactjs-flux, reactjs

Let me explain the problem that I've faced recently.

I have React.js + Flux powered application:

- There is a **list view**  of articles (NOTE: there are multiple of of different lists in the app) and article **details view** inside it.
- But there is only one API endpoint per each list which returns array of articles.
- In order to display the details I need to `find` article by id in array. That works pretty fine. I trigger action which makes request to server and propagates store with data, when I go to details screen then I just get the necessary article from that array in store.
- When user lands on article details view before list (stores are empty) then I need to make a request.
- Flow looks like: `User loads details view` -> `component did mount` -> `stores are empty` -> `rendered empty` -> `fetchArticles action is triggered` -> `request response is 200` -> `stores now have list of articles` -> `component did update` -> `rendered with data successfully`
- Component could look as follows:

  ```
  let DetailsComponent = React.createClass({
     _getStateFromStores() {
         let { articleId } = this.getParams();
         return {
             article: ArticleStore.getArticle(articleId)
         };
     },

     componentDidMount() {
         // fire only if user wasn't on the list before
         // stores are empty
         if (!this.state.article) {
            ArticleActions.fetchArticles('listType');
         }
     },

     render() {
        return <ArticleDetails article={this.state.article} />;
     }
  });
  ```

The interesting part comes next:

- **Now I need to make another request to server but request options depend on the article details**. That's why I need to make second request after the first one on the details view.
- I've tried several approaches but all of them look ugly. I don't like calling actions from stores that makes stores too complicated. Calling action inside action in this case doesn't work well because I will need to find article from store inside that action.

#### Solution (?!)

- What I've came up with is to use callback in action inside component and it feels much more cleaner:

  ```
  let DetailsComponent = React.createClass({
     _getStateFromStores() {
         let { articleId } = this.getParams();
         return {
             article: ArticleStore.getArticle(articleId)
         };
     },

     componentDidMount() {
         if (!this.state.article) {
            ArticleActions.fetchArticles('listType', () => {
                this._requestAdditionalData();
            });
         }
         this._requestAdditionalData();
     },

     _requestAdditionalData() {
         if (this.state.article) {
            ArticleActions.fetchAdditional(this.state.article.property);
         }
     },

     render() {
        return <ArticleDetails article={this.state.article} />;
     }
  });
  ```

What's your input?

Comment: This is not a real answer, but if you are always making two successive calls is there a way to batch them into one? E.g. always include the additional property with your original fetch?

Comment: This code is demonstrative, in reality it's more complex, batching won't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider move the second call to get a detail article to the ArticleDetails component componentDidMount() life cycle method.

So if the article is not set, do not render the ArticleDetails component at all by return null / false.

Comment: I agree with you. Thought like that came to my mind but the quickiest solution was to use callback.