# React.js + Flux -- Passing callback as a prop in view

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, reactjs, flux

The official [React.js tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) has an interesting practice of passing a callback as a prop to a child component.  In their example, they have a parent component named `CommentBox` and a child component named `CommentForm`.  The parent (`CommentBox`) passes a callback method `handleCommentSubmit` to the child (`CommentForm`).  When the form is submitted, the child component fires the callback to notify the parent that the form has been submitted.

However, this React tutorial is *not* a tutorial on the [Flux architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html).  From my limited flux perspective, my first instinct is that the child view should call an action, which (via the global dispatch system) updates a store.  The updated store would then trigger an update of any component that cared to know, including the parent component in question, the `CommentBox`.

In other words, the parent component would not care, nor would it want to know about what its child, the `CommentForm` is doing, or when the form is submitted.  Instead, it would rerender when the store is updated.  This means that *anything* that triggers a store update would cause the `CommentBox` to be updated (this is a good thing in my opinion; what if there were multiple ways of submitting a comment?)

This brings me to my main question:  Are there ever situations in the Flux architecture in which it *would* be appropriate to pass a callback method to a child component, or is this in general an anti-pattern?

---

Note: [Flux + React.js - Callback in actions is good or bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148539/flux-react-js-callback-in-actions-is-good-or-bad) is not the same question -- I'm asking about callbacks in views, not in the actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a pure UI component, like a fancy button, it makes sense to enable callbacks in the UI; actions should only be used for triggering application changes:

```
<MyFancyButton onClick={this.handleClick}/>
```

Obviously, `MyFancyButton` doesn't have enough information to know what the click should do; it'd be up to the parent view that uses it to decide which actions to dispatch.

Comment: In the react tutorial, would the `CommentForm` be considered a pure UI component?  i.e how do you qualify "pure UI" component?

Comment: I guess it'd depend on if the component owns/affects application state or if it just has state relating to its interactivity. Something like a comment form could go either way; either it's a general-purpose comment form that has no idea what it submits to, or it's a comment form that is tied to an application-specific purpose.